# Why files in this SEC filing is not downloadable?

Tags: data, historical-data, fundamentals, sec

[Quarterly report for MC Donalds](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/63908/0000063908-95-000025-index.html) has list of documents but there's no way to download it.

It has only one text file available for the download.

How the other documents could be downloaded, like the "10-Q" report file?[image: t]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome.

You're looking at 1995 data. Back then, Edgar was just coming online. They did not have documents in electronic form. If you want data that old, you may have to pay a vendor, such as S&P.

If you look at the same Макдак for 2019 https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000063908 , everything can be downloaded.

Comment: I see, thanks. But the whole reason I'm looking for SEC is because of old historical data.

Comment: I don't belive Edgar has data that old, sorry. I used to get old data from CompuStat, which got bought/merged into https://www.spglobal.com/marketintelligence/ S&P Market Intellgence. You may also be able to get it via Wharton Research Data Service https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/ .